# Using JAVA and regex to find a part of the URL

Tags: java, regex

I have a URL which can be

```
"http://example.com/bar1/checkstatus" or "http://example.com/bar2/checkstatus"
```

What's the most effective way to search for this URL using the .matches() function in JAVA where `example.com` remains constant, followed by `bar1` or `bar2`. Rest of the URL can vary.

Comment: What are your *exact and comprehensive* requirements? What have you tried? How isn't it working?

Comment: After reading this several times, I’m still not sure whether you’re trying to locate a URL embedded in text, or trying to parse a URL into its parts.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is *don't do it that way*.

Instead, use the `URL` or `URI` class to parse the URL, then extract the "path" component an analyze it further.  (You *could* use a regex to search the path ... after the URL parser has dealt with the escaping.)

Why is using a regex search on the text of a URL a bad idea?

Because:

- some parts of a URL are case sensitive and others are not
- some parts of a URL may be encoded
- some parts of a URL may be order sensitive

A regex that takes account of these things is typically complicated and difficult to read.  And if you ignore them, your matching is liable to malfunction when presented with various edge-case URLs.

Comment: What you say definitely makes sense, however as per the above example, ```example.com/bar1``` and ```example.com/bar2``` is a fixed URL whose value is known. Hence I was thinking of the regex approach, something on the lines of 

` \/example.com\/(bar1|bar2)\/ `

(i am not sure if that is the correct syntax for JAVA, but when i use it with the .matches function, it returns a false)

Comment: The `match` method matches the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the best way, yet I'm guessing that you wish to search/capture the `checkstatus`s, for which we'd then start with a simple expression:

```
(?i)^https?://(?:w{3}\.)?example\.com/bar[12]/([^/]*)/?$
```

assuming that there would be optional `wwww.` (`(?:w{3}\.)?`), `http` or `https` (`s?`), and ending trailing slashes (`/?`), which if not, we can simply remove those from the expression:

```
(?i)^http://example\.com/bar[12]/([^/]*)$
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "(?i)^https?://(?:w{3}\\.)?example\\.com/bar[12]/([^/]*)/?$";
        final String string = "http://example.com/bar1/checkstatus\n"
             + "http://example.com/bar2/checkstatus\n"
             + "https://www.example.com/bar1/checkstatus\n"
             + "https://www.example.com/bar2/checkstatus\n"
             + "http://example.com/bar1/checkstatus/\n"
             + "http://example.com/bar2/checkstatus/\n"
             + "https://www.example.com/bar1/checkstatus/\n"
             + "https://www.example.com/bar2/checkstatus/";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: http://example.com/bar1/checkstatus
Group 1: checkstatus
Full match: http://example.com/bar2/checkstatus
Group 1: checkstatus
Full match: https://www.example.com/bar1/checkstatus
Group 1: checkstatus
Full match: https://www.example.com/bar2/checkstatus
Group 1: checkstatus
Full match: http://example.com/bar1/checkstatus/
Group 1: checkstatus
Full match: http://example.com/bar2/checkstatus/
Group 1: checkstatus
Full match: https://www.example.com/bar1/checkstatus/
Group 1: checkstatus
Full match: https://www.example.com/bar2/checkstatus/
Group 1: checkstatus
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tFjCCP/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/tFjCCP/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]